# recursively create new keys in dictionary if len(value) is greater than x

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where tha values are list of strings. I need to perform the sum of the word in the whole strings and, when I reach a number x, I need to go back to the previous string, duplicate the key (with maybe a _i as suffix) and insert the remaining strings in the new value. Also, I need to delete the remaining strings from the previous value. I need to do this also for the new keys created.

Example where x = 5:

```
initial_dict = {'key1': ['abc wer', 'defgh e', 'ij r', 'klmnopqr r', 'e r stuv', 'wxyz aaa', 'extra word'],
   'key2': ['ciao']}

output = {'key1': ['abc wer', 'defgh e'], 
'key1_1' : ['ij r', 'klmnopqr r'],
'key1_2' : [ 'e r stuv', 'wxyz aaa'],
'key1_3' : [ 'extra word'],
   'key2': ['ciao']}
```

So the sum of the words is always <= 5.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need recursion for this. Just write a loop.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I believe the answers here should do the trick: [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks)